# Why Collection-valued navigation properties return empty list and a reference link to the actual data in CRM 2016 WEB API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, crm, dynamics-crm-2016, odata-v4

I don't know why the collection-valued navigation properties are always return an empty list with a reference to the actual data link.

here's the query I tried :

```
GET <organization>/api/data/v8.0/new_subjectareas?$expand=new_product_new_subjectarea&$count=true
```

Response :

```
{
"@odata.context":"<organization>/api/data/v8.0/$metadata#new_subjectareas",
"@odata.count":150,
"value":[
{
"@odata.etag":"W/\"9644599\"",
"timezoneruleversionnumber":null,
"processid":null,
"_stageid_value":null,
"new_product_new_subjectarea":[],
"new_product_new_subjectarea@odata.nextLink":"<organization>/api/data/v8.0/new_subjectareas(622bcca9-8946-e511-80fb-00155d002810)/new_product_new_subjectarea"
},
....
```

How can I get the items within the navigation property (new_product_new_subjectarea) without make a new request to it's reference (new_product_new_subjectarea@odata.nextLink)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour you are seeing is "by design" (even if one could argue that this particular design choice is questionable).

When you expand a collection-valued navigation property, you will always get an empty array plus a `[relation name]@odata.nextLink` property. There is currently no way of getting the actual relation rows without making an additional request.

Source: [the example in the official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx#Retrieve%20related%20entities%20by%20expanding%20navigation%20properties).

Comment: That's totally true but it's really a pity there isn't a way of getting it in the same call...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are returning to many entities.

[image]

source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx#bkmk_limits